# C Program - combine 2 strings during loop

Tags: c, string, for-loop, merge

This program is supposed to take two strings and merge each element one by one during a loop. For example, if I have the
        
first string as: hlowrd
 and the
        second string as: el ol 
the final string should be hello world
However, when the second string is longer than the first it will cut off the remaining characters. I believe it has to do with the with I structured my for loop in the function combine, however I'm not sure how to approach fixing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 50

int read_text(char *str, int n);
void combine(char *s3, const char *s1, const char *s2);

int main(void)
{
    char string1[N+1];  
    char string2[N+1];
    char string3[N+1];
    printf("Enter: \n");
    read_text(string1, N);
    printf("Enter: \n");
    read_text(string2, N);
    combine(string3, string1, string2);
    printf("New string is:  %s\n", string3);
    return 0;
}

int read_text(char *str, int n)
{
    int ch, i = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (i < n) {
            *str++ = ch;
            i++;
        }
    }
    *str = '\0';
    return i;
}

void combine(char *s3, const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    const char *s;
    s = s1;

    for( s = s3; *s1 != '\0'; s++) {
        strcpy(s3++, s1++);
        strcpy(s3++, s2++);
    }
    *s3 = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently only stop when at the end of the first string. You want to stop at the end of the shorter string, then add the remainder from the longer.

Change the condition in your `for` loop to be

```
for (;*s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0';) {...}
```

(or just change it to a `while` loop, since you don't need the variable `s` anyway):

```
while (*s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0') {...}
```

to stop when at the end of the shortest string and, after the loop, add

```
if (*s1 == '\0')
    strcpy(s3, s2);
else if (*s2 == '\0')
    strcpy(s3, s1);
```

to concatenate the remainder of the longer string to the output.

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop on either remaining source string being non empty, but also you can't really use strcpy as you're doing a char-by-char merge.  Try this:

```
void
combine(char *s3,const char *s1,const char *s2)
{
    int c1;
    int c2;

    c1 = *s1;
    c2 = *s2;

    while ((c1 != 0) || (c2 != 0)) {
        if (c1 != 0) {
            *s3++ = c1;
            c1 = *++s1;
        }

        if (c2 != 0) {
            *s3++ = c2;
            c2 = *++s2;
        }
    }

    *s3 = 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy` does work, albeit a little (okay, a lot) inefficient inside the loop. I tested the code with it, and it works fine.

Comment: @owacoder That's an answer [which I knew before posting].  Not using strcpy, is cleaner, simpler(!), and is the _practical_ answer you should be striving for.  For me [C for 30+ years], strcpy is a bug [because it's way_ far from optimal] and I'd file a bug report. Review your code vs mine.  Your code showed that you really didn't understand the problem/solution--that's the real issue.  wrench _can_ be a hammer--sometimes.  But, mag by 1000x in a real code base and it's nontrivial.  Always keep the code as simple as it needs to be [and no simpler].  Also, check ego at door ...

Comment: I know completely where you are coming from. However, I was not trying to use a "wrench as a hammer." I'm sorry if it came across that way. Personally, I would not use my answer's code in production. However, it *did* solve the OP's problem (for now, without much modification). I have nothing against your method, and would actually advocate it. My answer (and comment) were strictly a quick fix. For a long term fix and improvement, I would definitely choose your answer. I was simply pointing out in my comment that `strcpy` in this instance would *work*, but not necessarily *well*.

Comment: @owacoder Sorry--thought you _were_ OP [my bad].  If len(s1)==len(s2), let n=len(s1).  For linear, it's 2n s3 writes and 2n reads [and no fnc calls].  With strcpy, it's n^2 s3 writes and n^2 reads [and n^2 strcpy].  So, we go from O(4n) to O(2(n^2)).  Most people prefer to go the _other_ way :-)  If OP had mapped out with pen&paper first (i.e. _think_), he would have seen that strcpy was wrong _before_ coding the loop.  Maybe still the loop stop issue, but that's not so bad--he's [obviously] just learning.